# ActiveReports - reset page number for each group (page report)

Tags: .net, activereports

How do I print the current page number within a group on a Page Report created with ActiveReports 9?  I have a group setup in the Fixed Page, Grouping property and want the page number to reset for each new value of the group.

The following expression prints the current page of the total in the whole report:

```
="Page " & [&PageNumberInSection] & " of " & [&TotalPagesInSection]
```

The documentation shows how to accomplish this with a Section Report using a "ReportInfo" control, but it looks like that control is not available in a Page Report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: there is a check-box that needs to be enabled under the Fixed Layout Settings, then Grouping, in the Layout tab enable the "Has own page numbering" checkbox.